# Why are Unity iOS apps so big?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 2019.2.7 to build a medium size app (same app for Android is around 80 MB). My .IPA file is around 110 MB and when I download it from the app store or testflight it's around 330 MB. Is there anything I can do to reduce the size of this app in the app store?

Comment: iOS apps are unzipped when installed. Android apps stays inside the compressed apk file. What you can do is to use compressed asset bundles in the streaming asset folder.

Comment: I'm not talking about unzipped sized when its installed. I'm talking about the download size. Textures are fine because they don't cause the same issues on android right?

Comment: Don't trust the values in the app store or testflight, they are the install size, not the download size. You can check in App Store Connect under you app > Activity > All Builds > Build > "App Store File Sizes" the download size and the install size.

Comment: thank you, that was it, its says 90 MB there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**iOS apps are unzipped when installed.** Android apps stays inside the compressed apk file. What you can do is to use compressed asset bundles in the streaming asset folder.

**Don't trust the size values in the App Store or Testflight, they are the install size, not the download size.** You can check in App Store Connect under you app > Activity > All Builds > Build > "App Store File Sizes" the download size and the install size.

Comment: thanks, i'm not allowed to give you the bounty yet by the system